# Javascript some for nested array

Tags: javascript

this is my json data

```json
userpayment":[{"_id":"63297d5d1ae7697c5130fc8a","user_id":"632525106df51baf8b582803","coursepack":[{"third":"63291808acb84985480536b4"}]}]
```

here `"63291808acb84985480536b4"` how to `some` from this json

my code below

```js
userpayment.some(
    items => items.coursepack.some(
        its => its.third === "63291808acb84985480536b4"
    )
) ? true : false
```

Comment: need to check nested array object third

Comment: Can you please provide valid JSON data?

Comment: @todaysprint - yes, you do - but the issue is, what is the variable `userpayment`

Comment: and now, what is the variable that holds the data?

Comment: please check now updated

Comment: where is the variable `userpayment` defined?

Answer (score -1):

Given the first line is actually JSON - you need to parse it, then perform the `.some` on the correct path in the object

```js
const json = '{"users":{ "userpayment":[{"_id":"63297d5d1ae7697c5130fc8a","user_id":"632525106df51baf8b582803","coursepack":[{"third":"63291808acb84985480536b4"}]}]}}';
const data = JSON.parse(json);

const result = data.users.userpayment.some(items => items.coursepack.some(its =>its.third === "63291808acb84985480536b4"))

console.log(result);
```

or with minimal changes to your code (no changes)

```js
const json = '{"users":{ "userpayment":[{"_id":"63297d5d1ae7697c5130fc8a","user_id":"632525106df51baf8b582803","coursepack":[{"third":"63291808acb84985480536b4"}]}]}}';
const {users: {userpayment}} = JSON.parse(json);

const result = userpayment.some(items => items.coursepack.some(its =>its.third === "63291808acb84985480536b4"))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check This one,

```js
let y = [{
        "userpayment" : {
            "_id":"63297d5d1ae7697c5130fc8a",
            "user_id":"632525106df51baf8b582803",
            "coursepack":[{ 
                "third":"63291808acb84985480536b4"
            }]
        }
        
    }]


let yo = y.map( item => {
    
    const { userpayment } = item
    
    return userpayment.coursepack.some((itemCourse) => {
        return itemCourse.third == "63291808acb84985480536b4"
    })

})

console.log(yo)
```

Answer (score -1):

this is your JSON data:

```js
let userpayment = '[{"_id":"63297d5d1ae7697c5130fc8a","user_id":"632525106df51baf8b582803","coursepack":[{"third":"63291808acb84985480536b4"}]}]'
```

we'll make an experment:

```js
console.log(typeof userpayment ); // string
```

as you see js read userpayment as a string, not array containing an object,
so you first need to convert it from string to JS Object using JSON.parse()

```
let JSOBJ = JSON.parse(userpayment);
console.log(typeof JSOBJ); // object
```

now we have an array contains object:

```js
console.log(JSOBJ);
```

[image]

NOW you can some that array or do anything like seeing length... deal with it as a normal array

```js
JSOBJ.some(
    items => items.coursepack.some(
        its => its.third === "63291808acb84985480536b4"
    )
) ? console.log(true) : console.log(false)
```